# How to reconcile android cursor '_id' column with remote server db UIDs?

Tags: android, cursor

Can anyone clarify how loading server side data into an android sqlite db via a cursor should work with regards to ids? 
Should I have '_id' column in each table *and* also  a column with my server side uids? This seems awkward. 
I am missing whether I can just insert my own row ids (from a PostgreSql db) into the '_id' column and whether there are some implications of this that will make me sorry later?

Answer (score 0):

`_id` is used only in CursorAdapter to determine which column is id. You can override this behavior in CursorAdapter or add alias in query to id.

Comment: Ok I am confused because of text like this [Notepad doc](http://androidapps.org.ua/i_sect11_d1e7981.html) : "The value of each _id must be unique within the content provider; ... the _id should have the type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ...This helps support referential integrity..." My remote db may be updated outside of android. I don't see how I can alias my own uid column with _id and use those remote ids - ie no AUTOINCREMENT column in the content provider *and* also originate new rows on the android. Help with this common pattern very appreciated. Thanks Alex

Comment: Content providers are good for simple solutions. In such scenario you must be able to modify data, resolve conflicts etc. Read about SQLiteDatabase. As documentation says: "If you don't need to share data amongst multiple applications you can use a database directly via SQLiteDatabase".

Comment: Finally found someone with [the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266860/setting-the-id-field-using-sqlite-contentprovider-in-android) which suggests an extra foreign key column to hold the mapping to the remote db row id.

Comment: Thanks Dziobas - it's true - I don't (at the moment) need to share data but I have got the strong message that if I want my app to behave nicely, share device resources, not get shut down etc. I basically have to buy in to Content Providers,Services, SyncAdapters etc. If this not true, it would be great to see a complex app example (ie one that has remote+local data, sync requirements, authentication etc) -  which doesn't use all those components - ie not Notepad example.